# Cannot send emails using drupal 8 rules

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-rules

I have the drupal 8 varbase distribution with the rules plugin installed.
(version Rules: 8.x-3.0-alpha4
Typed Data: 8.x-1.0-alpha1)

When I make a rule to send an email when a user changes his/her account, I get the following error:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>   Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Drupal\user\Entity\User could not be converted to string in Drupal\Core\Mail\Plugin\Mail\PhpMail->format() (line 32 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Mail/Plugin/Mail/PhpMail.php).

I use direct input data for all fields of the form, no data selectors. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updates to drupal solved the issue, this question can be deleted.